# EF Migration ignores [Required] attribute on string properties and creates nullable field

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I must be missing something trivial. I think this is the first time I'm encountering this.

I expanded my `ApplicationUser : IdentityUser` class with some basic data. Some of it is required, some is optional. A simplified extract:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Date")]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    public string NationalNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `FirstName` and `LastName` are required, `NationalNumber` is not. `BirthDate`, being `nullable`, isn't either. This results in the following automatically generated code:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.AspNetUsers",
    c => new
    {
        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
        UserName = c.String(),
        PasswordHash = c.String(),
        SecurityStamp = c.String(),
        FirstName = c.String(),
        LastName = c.String(),
        BirthDate = c.DateTime(storeType: "date"),
        NationalNumber = c.String(),
        Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

The only columns which are created as `nullable: false` are the `Id` and `Discriminator` columns which are inherited from the `IdentityUser` class. Why are my `[Required]` attributes getting ignored ?

Comment: Is the `ApplicationUser` and `dbo.AspNetUsers` a copy-paste error in your question?

Comment: Not a copy/paste error. I suppose that's the new [ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx) which contains a rule that automatically 'translates' the used subclass of `IdentityUser` to `dbo.AspNetUsers`.
It's very well possible that this kind of 'magic' is the reason why the `[Required]` attributes get ignored on the `IdentityUser` subclass :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using inheritance and EF implements that using [table per hierarchy](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx) by default. `IdentityUser`s and `ApplicationUser`s will be stored in the same table. But `IdentityUser`s don't have `FirstName` or `LastName` properties so the fields in the database have to be nullable. If that is a problem for you then you need to use one of the other strategies:

[Table per type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) or [table per concrete type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this information! I'm glad there's a logical reason behind it. I'm not sure though if it's possible or desirable to use a different inheritance 'strategy' for this `IdentityUser` object which is automatically translated into the `"dbo.AspNetUsers"` table.
I'll research this a bit further and experiment with it when I have a bit more free time.